# How can I monitor a screen session with Python?

Tags: python, linux, bash

I need to monitor a `screen` session in real time using a Python script.  It needs to know when the display changes.  I believe this can be described as whenever `stdout` is flushed, or a character is entered to `stdin`.  Is there some way to do this; perhaps with pipes?

I have some code found [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/134892/) that gets a character from stdin, and I assume works on a pipe (if I modify the code, or change `sys.stdin`)?

Does the `flush` function of a stream (like `stdout`) get called in a pipe, or is it just called explicitly?  My understanding is that the display is only updated when `stdout` is flushed.

Comment: Do you mean monitor the shell?

Comment: Yes.  For example, if the user types `ls` and presses enter, I want the prompt, each of those key strokes, and the output of the ls command as seen by the user.  Basically, each time the the display is changed, I want to be notified of the new current display.

Comment: @JoeDoherty, I made an edit that hopefully explains better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you want to take a look at [`script`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/script.1), which already does pretty much everything you want.

Comment: Thanks, look like it does.  I saw it mentioned on my searches; but just people complaining about it :-p

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried python [curses](http://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html)? It is similar of Linux curses and provides a good way to handle terminal related i/o.